# how to save large decimal data from dataframe to csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

data frame consists of  13977 rows and 1280 columns and each cell has minimum  11 digit decimal number.
when i was trying to convert the data frame  to c.s.v file .In the file the whole decimal number is not
storing. it is saving up-to some decimals.
for eg:
0.1336052119731903 this is one of the number in the data frame but in c.s.v file it is storing  as 0.133605211

Answer (score 0):

Pandas by default has limit for the column width. If its longer then the limit its going to truncate the data stored in the column.

You can bypass the setting  like this:

```
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", 10000)
```

Cheers!

Comment: sir i have tried this but there is no change in displaying  last 2 digits  are not displaying. while printing after reading that csv it is not displaying all decimals

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of column to a string before exporting the data frame to a CSV file.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map(str)
df.to_csv("filename.csv")
```

If you are opening the CSV file in excel, you may have to custom format the cell for all the digits to be displayed.

Comment: sir i tried this but it is still showing some digits i have not find any options in the format of the cell for displaying all the digits

Comment: @NeeharikaBanisetti my solution and Geometrein's solution will solve this problem in my understanding. If you are viewing the exported CSV in MS Excel, check the formula bar, if it is displaying all the digits, we can assume that exporting to CSV is successful. 
Follow the below steps to display all the digits.
Right-click one of the cells and click "Format Cells" to open the Format Cells dialogue window.
Click the "Custom" tab and review the formats in the Category section. (#,##0.00000000000000) this format will work.

Comment: sir while storing last digit is missing  and while reading the csv file into dataframe again. then also the last digit  is not printing sir i have tried every method sir but it could not work out. could you help me with this sir